# javascript - how to limit form submit to 20 submits without email address duplication?

Tags: javascript

So I want to have a form that limits registered user to at least 20 without email address duplication. When it already hits 20, the form closes

Comment: so you want validation of email can we wrong 20 times not more than that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should track the number of users at the server side and use this number to show or hide your form after a particular threshold.

For email verification your app should have some server side logic which will be called whenever some one enters an email and if this email exist already then your form's submit button should be disable.

I hope this will help.

Comment: it's an Eloqua form though. Email address is the unique key.